# list contributions to any repositorie (not only owned ones) of a user in github

Tags: github, repository

I have a very simple question. I am trying to figure out the repositories a github user has contributed to and I am unable. So for example in this account https://github.com/goodfeli. How can I check all the repositories this user has contributed to?

By clicking into repositories I can only list the repositories created by this user. Moreover, I know the pinned repositories can show any repository this user has contributed to but it can only list up to 6. So I can figure out how to list them all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/about-the-graphql-api) to get up to 100 repositories where a user contributed to for various categories. This displays repositories that are accessible by the token you are authenticating with.

Here is a query (replace `octocat` with the login of the user):

```
query {
  user(login: "octocat") {
    contributionsCollection {
      commitContributionsByRepository(maxRepositories: 100) {
        repository {
          nameWithOwner
        }
      }
      issueContributionsByRepository(maxRepositories: 100) {
        repository {
          nameWithOwner
        }
      }
      pullRequestReviewContributionsByRepository(maxRepositories: 100) {
        repository {
          nameWithOwner
        }
      }
      pullRequestContributionsByRepository(maxRepositories: 100) {
        repository {
          nameWithOwner
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The simplest way is to use GitHub's [GraphQL Explorer](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer) where you can refine/adjust your query.

The user you are mentioning in your question apparently has no contributions that are accessible with my authenticated user, thus the result is empty:

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "contributionsCollection": {
        "commitContributionsByRepository": [],
        "issueContributionsByRepository": [],
        "pullRequestReviewContributionsByRepository": [],
        "pullRequestContributionsByRepository": []
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That user that was just an example so not really interested in listing its contributions. Is there any way we can do this via de github.com webpage?